# Chinese Sports Competition

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, knowledge

A new fantastic sport has gripped China called MetalBall! All city teams have picked mascots/emblems and registered one of three separate divisions. All city teams are listed below in alphabetical order. Some cities have had enough players to form multiple teams and entered multiple times within or across divisions. Determine what the prize is by determining the results of the first week of competition.

```
City Name -- Mascot/Emblem
--------------------------
Ankang -- Meowth
Anqiu -- Magikarp
Bozhou -- Psyduck
Changsha -- Ivory Helmets
Dongying -- Dark Scarves
Fuyang -- Lion
Gaoan -- Bull
Gujiao -- Eevee
Hancheng -- Rooster
Hancheng -- Voltorb
Hancheng -- Jade Socks
Handan -- Gyarados
Heze -- Tiger
Heze -- Cow
Huanghua -- Leopard
Huozhou -- Ram
Jiangshan -- Ekans
Jiangyan -- Lioness
Jincheng -- Golden Mask
Jincheng  -- Lavender Gloves
Jining -- Leopardess
Kaifeng -- Stallion
Kaifeng -- Golduck
Laohekou -- Flareon
Lichuan -- Exeggcute
Linyi -- Crimson Sleeves
Lishui -- Stag
Nanchang -- Boar
Nangong -- Spearow
Qingdao -- Tigress
Qingdao -- Doe
Qinyang -- Drake
Qinyang -- Fearow
Rugao -- Redarms
Shangrao -- Azure Pants
Shiyan -- Tiercel
Taiyuan -- Hen
Tongren -- Kabuto
Weihui -- Greenfeet
Wuan -- Ewe
Xianning -- Wolverine
Xingtai -- Magenta Capes
Xinyang -- Omanyte
Xinyang -- Blacknecks
Xuanzhou -- Exeggutor
Yanan -- Electrode
Yantai -- Pinkback
Yichang -- Purplefingers
Yima -- Persian
Yingcheng -- Arbok
Yingcheng -- Kabutops
Yingcheng -- Omastar
Yongkang -- Sow
Yuanjiang -- Angeline
Yuanping -- Whitehairs
Yueyang -- Duck
Yuncheng -- Mare
Zaoyang -- Meltan
Zaozhuang -- Bluelegs
Zhucheng -- Melmetal
Zhumadian -- Hawk
Zhumadian -- Yellowface
```

Comment: For Handan did you mean for the team to be Garados or is it meant to be Gyarados.

Comment: @gabbo1092 Yes, sorry for the typo. Thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 3):

## Partial Answer

First off the three divisions are:

> Pokémon, Animals and colour-bodypart/colour-clothing.

Each team in the divisions has a counterpart:

> For the pokemon its the next evolution, for the animals its male and female, and for last group it is in the form 'colour clothes' matched with 'colourbodypart' where the colours and clothes to body part correlate.

Separating into these groups and matches gives:

> ```
> City Name -- Mascot/Emblem 
>
> Ankang -- Meowth                 Yima -- Persian 
> Anqiu -- Magikarp                Handan -- Gyarados 
> Bozhou -- Psyduck                Kaifeng -- Golduck 
> Gujiao -- Eevee                  Laohekou -- Flareon 
> Hancheng -- Voltorb              Yanan -- Electrode 
> Jiangshan -- Ekans               Yingcheng -- Arbok 
> Lichuan -- Exeggcute             Xuanzhou -- Exeggutor 
> Nangong -- Spearow               Qinyang -- Fearow 
> Tongren -- Kabuto                Yingcheng -- Kabutops 
> Xinyang -- Omanyte               Yingcheng -- Omastar 
> Zaoyang -- Meltan                Zhucheng -- Melmetal 
>
>  
> Changsha -- Ivory Helmets        Yuanping -- Whitehairs 
> Dongying -- Dark Scarves         Xinyang -- Blacknecks 
> Hancheng -- Jade Socks           Weihui -- Greenfeet 
> Jincheng -- Golden Mask          Zhumadian -- Yellowface 
> Jincheng  -- Lavender Gloves     Yichang -- Purplefingers 
> Linyi -- Crimson Sleeves         Rugao -- Redarms 
> Shangrao -- Azure Pants          Zaozhuang -- Bluelegs 
> Xingtai -- Magenta Capes         Yantai -- Pinkback 
>
>  
> Fuyang -- Lion                   Jiangyan -- Lioness 
> Gaoan -- Bull                    Heze -- Cow 
> Hancheng -- Rooster              Taiyuan -- Hen 
> Heze -- Tiger                    Qingdao -- Tigress 
> Huanghua -- Leopard              Jining -- Leopardess 
> Huozhou -- Ram                   Wuan -- Ewe 
> Kaifeng -- Stallion              Yuncheng -- Mare 
> Lishui -- Stag                   Qingdao -- Doe 
> Nanchang -- Boar                 Yongkang -- Sow 
> Qinyang -- Drake                 Yueyang -- Duck 
> Shiyan -- Tiercel                Zhumadian -- Hawk 
> Xianning -- Wolverine            Yuanjiang -- Angeline
> ```